# How to pass thread local variable in Project Reactor

Tags: project-reactor

I started using project reactor. Does anyone know how can I pass thread local variables from one thread to another? I saw some methods on `Hooks.java` but could not figure out what is the recommended way of doing this. Can someone point me to some documentation or with a code snippet on how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I have a working example in this github repository based on the [spring-cloud-sleuth](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth)'s implementation: https://github.com/gumartinm/JavaForFun/tree/master/SpringJava/WebReactive/spring-webreactive-reactor-context-enrich

The key classes are: [ContextCoreSubscriber.java](https://github.com/gumartinm/JavaForFun/blob/master/SpringJava/WebReactive/spring-webreactive-reactor-context-enrich/src/main/java/de/spring/example/reactor/thread/context/enrichment/subscriber/ContextCoreSubscriber.java), [SubscriberContext.java](https://github.com/gumartinm/JavaForFun/blob/master/SpringJava/WebReactive/spring-webreactive-reactor-context-enrich/src/main/java/de/spring/example/reactor/thread/context/enrichment/subscriber/SubscriberContext.java), [ThreadContextEnrichmentAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/gumartinm/JavaForFun/blob/master/SpringJava/WebReactive/spring-webreactive-reactor-context-enrich/src/main/java/de/spring/example/reactor/thread/context/enrichment/configuration/ThreadContextEnrichmentAutoConfiguration.java) and [UsernameFilter.java](https://github.com/gumartinm/JavaForFun/blob/master/SpringJava/WebReactive/spring-webreactive-resources/src/main/java/de/spring/example/rest/filter/UsernameFilter.java)

- ContextCoreSubscriber.java:
  Enables you to fill the Mapped Diagnostic Context: [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)
- SubscriberContext.java:
  Helper class for inserting data in the Reactor's Context.
- ThreadContextEnrichmentAutoConfiguration.java:
  In charge of configuring the Reactor's Hooks: [Hooks.onEachOperator](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#hooks-assembly)
- UsernameFilter.java:
  Example where we want to register the username information based on some HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor doesn't guarantee that the processing done by a `Flux` or `Mono` chain of operators will stick executing on a single thread. On the contrary, it performs work-stealing and lets the user switch execution context.

As such, using `ThreadLocal` is not very adapted to Reactor.

There is currently some work done in `3.1.0` towards providing an equivalent, at least for library authors that use Reactor, but nothing definite in place yet.
Keep your eyes peeled for `3.1.0`, that should be the main theme of that release (and will probably be the focus of the second upcoming milestone, M2).

Comment: By now the "Context" is available in Project Reactor http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_using_the_context

Comment: @Simon would you please clarify the meaning of 'work-stealing' in reactor and give some examples if possible? it is known that spring Sleuth performs a tuning of used reactor schedulers (`Schedulers.setFactory(...)`) so thread-local data can be transferred between threads on swithing executing context. I worry if there are scenarios when operator will use the thread which was not created/tuned by Scheduler's factory before. thanks.